# How to serialize an object to an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, serialization, nsdictionary

I want to serialize an object to an NSDictionary.

(key = value) will be (property-name = property-value)

If a property is another object, it will be recursively serialized as another NSDictionary inside the parent NSDictionary.

Does anyone have an idea? API? Pointer? Reflection? framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a pointer: `void *(*(*foo)())(char *)`

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose do you need to turn an object into a dictionary?

If it is to save the object to a file, you should look at the NSCoder protocol, which you can implement for your object so that an array of your objects (for example) can be serialized by built in methods like NSArray's -writeToFile:atomically:.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have an object that I want to serialize as NSDictionary because I'm adding it's keys and values to a GET request parameters.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is a method on your object that just produces an NSDictionary for your use...

Answer (score 1):

Adopting `NSCoding` is certainly an option -- basically, your graph's elements would all need to know how to serialize/deserialize themselves (by adopting `NSCoding`). Under this approach, you would use the `NSCoder` interfaces for archiving and unarchiving.

Another common alternative would be a property list. This is a simpler more portable format with some restrictions to types. Namely, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber` (and `CFBoolean`), `NSData`, and `NSDate` - as well as their CoreFoundation counterparts. These types and collections all know how to serialize their elements appropriately. Here, you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` for archiving and unarchiving. This is not much overhead for smaller tasks, but `NSCoding` is generally a better long term solution where portability is not a concern (e.g. export as XML) because the objects can maintain their serialization implementations without much intervention from the archiver.

For custom objects, you would typically support either a property list representation and/or `NSCoding` - but the collections types already know how to archive and unarchive themselves (provided of course their contents also support the approach to serialization you use).

More details can be found in Apple's '[Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.pdf)'.